# Prove that a linear and continuous operator admits inverse in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(H,(\cdot,\cdot))$ an Hilbert space and $A:H\rightarrow H$ a linear and continuous operator such that there exists $\alpha >0$ such that $$(Au,u)\geq \alpha \|u\|^2 \text{ for each } u\in H.$$

Prove that $A$ is invertible and $\|A^{-1}\|\leq {1\over \alpha}$.

I've already proved that $A$ is injective, regarding surgectivity, my professor suggested first to prove that $Im(A)$ is closed in $H$ and then that $Im(A)$ is dense.

I've thought to take a sequence $(v_h)_h\subset Im(A)$ such that there exists $v\in H$ such that $$v_h\rightarrow v \text{ in } H.$$

But now I can't prove that $v\in Im(A)$, and also I really would appreciate if someone could give me some hints to solve the other points.

Comment: If $X$ is a Banach space, $T \colon X \to Y$ a linear map to a normed space $Y$ such that there is a $c > 0$ with $\lVert Tx\rVert \geqslant c\lVert x\rVert$ for all $x\in X$, can you see that the range of $T$ is closed? For the denseness of the range of $A$, consider an $u \in (\operatorname{im} A)^\perp$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $v_h=Au_h$ for some (actually a unique) $u_h$. Using the assumption with $u:=u_k-u_j$, we obtain after an application of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that $(u_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ is Cauchy.

For density, notice that if $v$ is orthogonal to the range of $A$, then $(Av,v)=0$.

For the norm inequality, use $(A(A^{-1}u),A^{-1}u)\geqslant\alpha (A^{-1}u,A^{-1}(u))$ and Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints! I didn't know there was a characterisation for dense subspace in a Hilbert space, but now I know:)